# Composer codeIgniter "nothing to install or update" even add library into composer JSON

Tags: php, codeigniter

It's a long time i didn't use codeIgniter as my framework.
I'm gonna install library using composer in codeIgniter,

Library i want to install is [hybridauth](https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth) for social login with codeigniter.

I have added  `"hybridauth/hybridauth": "~3.0"` to my composer.json

Here is my whole `composer.json`

```
{
    "description": "The CodeIgniter framework",
    "name": "codeigniter/framework",
    "type": "project",
    "homepage": "https://codeigniter.com",
    "license": "MIT",
    "support": {
        "forum": "http://forum.codeigniter.com/",
        "wiki": "https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki",
        "slack": "https://codeigniterchat.slack.com",
        "source": "https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter"
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.7",
        "hybridauth/hybridauth": "~3.0"
    },
    "suggest": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "Provides better randomness in PHP 5.x"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "mikey179/vfsStream": "1.1.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.* || 5.*"
    }
}
```

Then, when i'm trying to install with this command `composer install`, there is nothing to install. The output of that command was like this:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in 
composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update 
them.
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

And when i'm trying to `composer update`, the output is like this:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package hybridauth/hybridauth master is satisfiable by 
hybridauth/hybridauth[dev-master] but these conflict with your requirements 
or minimum-stability.
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit

`"hybridauth/hybridauth": "~3.0"`

to

`"hybridauth/hybridauth": "*"`

then, run this command `composer update`.

it solves my problem now.